# Combined RLC circuit phasor diagram?

Tags: passive-networks, phasor

We have a circuit in the picture below. What will the phasor diagram look like in case: $$I_C<I_L$$ and $$I_C>>I_L$$ ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the capacitor, current will lead the excitation voltage by 90 degrees and the inductor current (with zero resistance for R) will lag by 90 degrees. As R increases, the current thru the inductor reduces and the phase angle moves from -90deg eventually to 0deg when R = infinity.

As for the total current taken, sum up the individual currents and you have your answer. If you think someone is going to spend time drawing a phasor diagram where R, L, C and F are all variable, think again.

Comment: Hhaha, great explanation, that's all I needed :D